# Can focus be remove from a control to modify its properties in VBA?

Tags: arrays, ms-access, data-binding, vba

First I remove control visibility by doing this:

```
For Each ctl In Me.MySubform.Controls
    ctl.Visible = False
Next ctl
```

and later, I go back and bind those controls I'm going to use for the current list of fields using an array of the caption and control source name.

```
For i = 0 To UBound(MyArray) Step 2
    Me.MySubform.Controls(i).ControlSource = MyArray(i)
    Me.MySubform.Controls(i + 1).Caption = MyArray(i + 1)
    Me.MySubform.Controls(i).Visible = True
    Me.MySubform.Controls(i + 1).Visible = True
Next i
```

The issue I run into is, if a user has clicked into one of these fields providing it with focus, I seem to set the control visible property to false or rebind the field to another field during the next refresh event.

I think by removing the controls focus I would be able to accomplish this; however, I have two concerns.

1. Is this possible in VBA (MS Access 2003)? If so how?
2. Is there a better more ideal way to accomplish this in this environment? If so, what options are available and what considerations go into picking a solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot change the visible property of a control that has focus. Is this the problem? If so, it can be useful to keep a small control to receive focus with SetFocus : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa205181(office.10).aspx